# Perl google calendar API

Tags: perl, google-calendar-api

I have written a Perl script which connects to Google calendar API. I encountered some issues.

I would like to delete the event that is `> "15 Feb 2013"` (event that having date `15 Feb 2013 onward`), I can't find the variable for this, could anyone advise?

Answer (score 3):

[Net::Google::Calendar](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Google-Calendar/) is an existing library to work with the Google Calendar API.  It has a [delete_entry method](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Google-Calendar/lib/Net/Google/Calendar.pm#delete_entry_%3CNet%3a%3aGoogle%3a%3aCalendar%3a%3aEntry%3E) which seems to be what you want.

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to find all events which start on 15-Feb-2013 and delete them?  I believe that would be...

```
use Net::Google::Calendar;

my $cal = Net::Google::Calendar->new;
$cal->login($username, $password);

my @events = $cal->get_events(
    start-min => "2013-02-15",
);
for my $event (@events) {
    $cal->delete_entry($event);
}
```

Using the raw API you'd use [list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to get the entry using timeMin and timeMax to search for it.  Then [delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) it using the eventId.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/$calendarId/events?timeMin=2013-02-15
```

Gets you a list of events and then...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/$calendarId/events/$eventId
```

On each of them to delete them.

But you should probably use the module.

Comment: I want to delete event that have start on 15 Feb 2013 and I dont have the max (what i mean don't have max because I would like to delete all the event start from date 15 Feb 2013. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to leave off the max.

Comment: when i run the above script, I am getting error "Can't locate object method "delete_entry" via package "Net::Google::Calendar::En
try" at C:\perl_apps\delete.pl line 20." Could anyone advise?

Comment: @user2081742 Sorry, I misread the docs and assumed you called `delete_entry` on the entry object.  You're supposed to call it on the calendar.  I've updated the code.

Comment: A review on cpan of Net::Google::Calendar claims it no longer works as it has not been updated to the newest google calendar API.

Comment: @Chris If that's so, it appears API::Google::GCal is being actively developed, though I have no idea of its quality. https://metacpan.org/pod/API::Google::GCal

Comment: NB - there are many cpan modules and most of them are rather poor .. if you've got time is probably worth going lower level https://blog.ludin.org/2017/01/15/using-google-apis-with-perl-part-3-simplicity/ .. the general soln above to get the list to obtain id's and then delete seems like the right approach though.